# Error creating orasession 429-activex component cant create object

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, vb6

I have installed VB6 on my new system with 64 bit OS and oracle client 11 g and in this process from the code I am trying to connect to the application's Oracle database. But I am getting the error that the object is not getting created.

I have tried registering the DLL's but still the same issue.

```
ErrPos = "Creating OraSession"
Set OraSession = CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession")
```

Comment: You have __tried__ or you __did__ register the DLL's? Big difference here.

Comment: I have registered the DLL's  which were missing when I opened the references tab in VB6.

Comment: If it's displayed in the reference tab, then can you not just use early binding? `Set OraSession = New ...`

Comment: Actually I am new to VB6 just started to work on this application.The same code was working in another system which was 32 bit and the object was getting created successfully but in my new system it is not getting created.

Comment: could you please help me how can I do the early binding.

Comment: Early vs late binding probably isn't the solution to this issue, but early binding can be a better coding practice in general.

Comment: Seeing if the DLL is available, in your references, may tell you if it's registered correct or not (plus you get code completion for the object)  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/adding-a-reference-to-a-visual-basic-project

Answer (score 0):

It's likely 1 of 2 issues.

1. It is not registered properly.  `c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe c:\oracle\client\11gR2\bin\OraOleDB11.dll`

or

2. It won't let you use the 64bit DLL from a VB6 application.  You want to verify the 32bit version is registered and sometimes you have to unregister and reregister these controls.

Comment: I have registered the OraOleDB11.dll but still the issue persists.where can I find the controls which are being used.

Comment: @JhimliNath Did you check the 32-bit vs 64-bit suggestion?

Comment: Jimmy, did you mean "libraries" or DLLs, and not "controls"?

Comment: Yep, I meant to say DLL as controls are separate in VB6 (*.OCX).  @JhimliNath did you verify if it's the 32 bit or 64 bit version?  Maybe re-download the DLL just to be sure.

Comment: @JhimliNath they can be tricky and sometimes it's good to search the registry for entries to the DLL  https://serverfault.com/questions/576831/how-do-i-know-if-a-dll-is-registered

Comment: My issue is resolved after installing 32 bit oracle client.I was using 64 bit oracle client since my system is 64 bit.Thanks all for the suggestions.